# Constructor overriding in PHP

Tags: php, constructor, overriding

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459795/php-constructor-inheritance), we need the same signature for the parent and child constructors.

But I tried the following code, and it is working fine. I am finding it difficult to understand this.

```
<?php
class Person{
    var $name;

    function __construct( string $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
class Student extends Person{
    public int $age;

    function __construct(int $age){
        $this->age = 0;
    }
}
$ob1 = new Person("David");
$ob2 = new Student(23);

echo "$ob1->name \n $ob2->age \n";

?>
```

Of course, `$ob2->name` is empty.  I am not even using `parent::__construct` as given in the manual. Is it because I use `var $name` in the base class instead of the typed variable `public int $name`?

*Edit*: I tried `public int $name` also, and it is working.

Comment: Here you are using 2 different class objects to access their own property. So why you are confused? this is an example of how a child overwrites parent: https://3v4l.org/0uu2d

Comment: But according to another answer (see the link in my question), we cannot do this.  That means, even before creating objects, it should throw an error.  Can you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: I haven't seen any such things in the link answers.

Comment: Constructors are the one thing that can be different without violating the LSP. Because of course each subclass might need different constructor arguments. Only the rest of the interface must be compatible.

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie: I am copying a line from the question. "My problem is that php doesn't allow me to make the child's constructor without the $something parameter i get the following:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things.

- *we need the same signature for the parent and child constructors.* Well, in case of constructors, this signature rule is exempted. [`See here`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#:%7E:text=Unlike%20other%20methods). Quoting from the [`manual`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop.lsp):

> When overriding a method, its signature must be compatible with the
> parent method. Otherwise, a fatal error is emitted, or, prior to PHP
> 8.0.0, an E_WARNING level error is generated. A signature is compatible if it respects the variance rules, makes a mandatory
> parameter optional, adds only optional new parameters and doesn't
> restrict but only relaxes the visibility. This is known as the Liskov
> Substitution Principle, or LSP for short. The constructor, and private
> methods are exempt from these signature compatibility rules, and thus
> won't emit a fatal error in case of a signature mismatch.

- When you don't mention any constructor in child class, it gets inherited from parent class(unless it is declared as private in parent class).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

class Person{
    var $name;

    function __construct( string $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
class Student extends Person{
    public int $age;
}

$ob = new Student("James");

echo $ob->name;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/97iKq)

The [`manual`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) on this states the same.

> Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
> defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
> parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the
> child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
> parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
> as private).

- In your case, you are overriding the constructor in your child class and not explicitly calling the parent class constructor. Since constructors are exempt from the LSP rule, the semantic and syntax is perfectly valid and doesn't emit any error.
  If you wish to initialize the `name` as well, you are allowed to create a new parameter for this in your child class constructor, pass in some value and then call the parent constructor to initialize values.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

class Person{
    var $name;

    function __construct(string $name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
class Student extends Person{
    public int $age;
    
    function __construct(int $age, string $name){
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}

$ob = new Student(25, "James");

echo $ob->age, " " ,$ob->name;
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/sWvoU)